# How computationally hard are the battle systems of Paper Mario and Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity, computer-games

What is the time complexity and space complexity of working out, in suitably generalised versions of the battle systems of both Paper Mario 64 and Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door:

- The minimum number of turns that Mario can win in
- The minimum number of turns that Mario can guarantee a win in

Of course, we could also consider the corresponding decision problems:

- Can Mario win in $N$ turns?
- Can Mario guarantee a win in $N$ turns?

For those of you on the Computer Science Stack Exchange who are not familiar with these games, I'll now give a brief explanation of the two games' battle systems. Mario and his enemies have a certain amount of HP (Heart Points). When Mario HP drops to zero, the battle is lost and the game over screen is displayed, unless Mario has a life shroom, in which case he is restored to 10 HP. If an enemy's HP drops to zero, the enemy is defeated, except in some special cases (e.g. Cortez from Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door has different forms, switching to the next form when his HP goes down to 0). Mario has a partner that can aid him in battle. "Basic" attacks, like Mario's regular jump and hammer attacks, Goombario's (Paper Mario 64) Headbonk, etc., can be done for free, but more complex attacks require FP (Flower Points). Both HP and FP can be recovered by eating items. Items can also be used to attack enemies. The battle system is turn based: first Mario and his partner attack (either Mario first or partner first, the player can choose), then the enemy closest to Mario attacks, then the next enemy, all the way to the last enemy. Mario and his enemies each have a certain amount of defence which reduces the amount of damage they take when attacked; the damage taken is the attack power minus the defence. Some attacks, like Watt's (Paper Mario 64) Electro Dash and Vivian's (Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door) Fiery Jinx, are piercing, which means that they ignore defence. Some enemies are immune against certain attack types, for example rock-based enemies are immune to fire-based attacks, so for example, Vivian's Fiery Jinx will do no damage. Some enemies are take more damage from certain attacks, for example fire-based enemies take additional damage from ice-based attacks.

Mario can guard against attacks, which decreases the damage he takes by one, and prevents status effects from being inflicted by attacks. In Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, he can superguard, which prevents him from taking any damage, and deals 1 damage to the enemy that attacked him if it was a direct attack. If a Pokey throws a body segment at Mario or his partner and the player successfully superguards, the body segment is bounced back to the Pokey, dealing the same amount of damage to the Pokey as the body segment throw attack would normally deal. Note that some attacks cannot be guarded or superguarded - for more information, see [the Mario Wiki article about superguarding](https://www.mariowiki.com/Superguard).

In Paper Mario 64, Mario's partners do not have HP - once they take damage, they are unable to take actions or be switched out for the number of turns equal to the damage taken. In Paper Mario 64, if Mario successfully guards against an attack, his partner will also guard against it, but unlike Mario, if one of his partners guards against an attack, they will take no damage. On Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, Mario's partners have HP, can guard and superguard like Mario, and when their HP drops to 0, they will get restored to 10 HP if Mario has a life shroom, otherwise they will be defeated, and while the battle will not be considered lost and the game over screen will not be displayed, the defeated partner will not be able to take actions until Mario heals them by using an item. Note that defeated partners in Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door can still be switched out.

If Mario jumps on or hammers an enemy in the field, it will perform a first strike, where Mario gets a bonus attack in addition to his other attacks that turn. Kooper (Paper Mario 64), Koops (Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door), Bombette (Paper Mario 64), and Bobbery (Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door) can also perform first strikes in a similar fashion. Enemies can also first strike Mario.

Mario can perform special moves using SP (star power), which is shared between him and his partner. These can be used to recover HP and FP and perform attacks. All special move attacks are piercing. In Paper Mario 64, SP is recovered slowly during battle, taking 8 turns to recover 1 SP, and Mario can also use Focus to restore $1/2$ SP. Mario's partner cannot use focus unless Mario has the Group Focus badge. Focus recovers more SP if Mario has a deep focus badge. In Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, a small amount of SP is recovered for each successful attack, and Mario and his partner can recover more perform Stylish moves when attacking and by appealing to the audience. How much SP is recovered depends on the audience size (0 audience members means 0 SP recovered), and the audience makeup. Mario recovers more SP by appealing if he has the Super Appeal badge; his partner recovers more SP by appealing if Mario has the Super Appeal P badge.

In Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, the audience can throw "items" at Mario and his partner. These can be coins; hearts (recover 1 HP on contact); flowers (recover 1 FP on contact); rocks, cans, hammers, or bones (cause 1 damage on contact); or actual items. For more information, see [TTYD YouTuber Malleo's video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUOxRX6tX6s). Some enemies can eat the audience, and Magnus von Grapple has an attack where he throws audience members at Mario and his partner.

In Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, depending on whether Mario is a Rising Star, B List Star, A List Star, or Superstar (which depends on his level), the stage can cause special effects, like fog, which causes Mario's, his partner's, and his enemies' attacks to sometimes miss. For more information about this paragraph and the two before it, see https://www.mariowiki.com/Audience.

Partners can learn new abilities by levelling up. There are three ranks: initial rank, super rank, and ultra rank.

Mario can use BP (Badge Points), which like HP and FP can be upgraded by levelling up, to equip badges. Badges can increase Mario's attack power, increase his defence, and do some other things. In Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, most badges have a normal version that just affects Mario, and a P version that only affects his partner. Note that our generalised versions of these games will allow for arbitrary BP and badge setup, so we do not need to have BP as part of the input - we can just take the badge setup as input and assume Mario has enough BP.

I hope I haven't made any errors in my explanation.

Here are some links where you can learn more about the battle systems of the two games:

- https://www.mariowiki.com/Paper_Mario
- https://www.mariowiki.com/Paper_Mario:_The_Thousand-Year_Door
- https://www.mariowiki.com/Action_Command
- https://www.mariowiki.com/Guard
- https://www.mariowiki.com/Superguard
- https://www.mariowiki.com/Paper_Mario_bestiary
- https://www.mariowiki.com/Paper_Mario:_The_Thousand-Year_Door_bestiary

For the generalisations of these two games, I will allow arbitrary max Mario HP, max FP, BP, badge setup, enemy count, enemy setup, and for TTYD, arbitrary max partner HP, audience size, and audience setup. The generalisations will have all instances of pseudo-randomness in their respective real video game replaced with true randomness. The generalisations will also be glitch free (e.g. double dipping an egg missile on Lava Piranha in our generalised version of Paper Mario 64 will just do the appropriate damage to Lava Piranha rather than causing the game to crash as it does in Paper Mario 64).

By "arbitrary badge setup", I mean that, although our generalised games will only use the badges present in their respective real games, they can use arbitrary badge combinations and arbitrarily many copies of each badge from their respective real games. Likewise, by "arbitrary enemy setup", I mean that, although our generalised games will only use the enemies present in their respective real games (with the same moves, max HP, and all other attributes), they will allow for any setup of those enemies, even those that cannot be found in their respective real games. Similarly, by arbitrary audience setup, I mean that our generalised version of Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door will use the same audience members as the actual Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door, but will allow for any setup of those possible audience members, even those that cannot occur in the actual Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door.

Comment: Can you please provide a link explaining the battle systems of those games?

Comment: This is not exactly the same game, but Mario has already been proven as [NP-hard](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1895.pdf).

Comment: Can you make your question self-contained by including in the question all information needed to understand the relevant aspects of these games?

Comment: There are a lot of rules and parameters to this game. I doubt a lot of people (if any) will want to go through all this to work out if it is (say) NP-Hard. If you are trying to do so yourself I suggest you start by making the problem as simple as possible (say get rid of items, badges and the like) and see what you can prove, then iterate from there.